# Using SQL Group by and SUM Function in Crystal Reports

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I'm trying to make a report using Crystal Report and I need to use Group by and Sum in order to get the data as needed. How can i put this query on CR or at least configure CR to work like the query.

Query:

```
SELECT hr_employees1.FirstName, hr_employees1.LastName, wagetypes1.Description, 
 SUM(wagetypeweight1.quantity), wagetypeweight1.date, wagetypes1.factor
 FROM   nomina_pelado.wagetypes wagetypes1 
 INNER JOIN (nomina_pelado.hr_employees hr_employees1 
 INNER JOIN nomina_pelado.wagetypeweight wagetypeweight1 
 ON hr_employees1.Employee=wagetypeweight1.employee) 
 ON wagetypes1.WageType=wagetypeweight1.wagetype
 WHERE  wagetypes1.factor='N'
 group by hr_employees1.Employee, DATE(wagetypeweight1.date)
```

In CR i already know how to put the where sentence, what i need to know, if possible, how to put the "Group by" sentence.

Comment: the report dataset in CR should be raw data, then group and sum them in CR that's how a reporting tool works

Comment: if you want to display the summary only then your script will just working fine